# Paypal API - Can we transfer money to single account from multiple senders in a transaction?

Tags: paypal

Let us assume that some money is deposited to the admins account when a user signups . Now the same user when goes to buy a item he gets some kind of discount for ex:- the item he wants to buy costs $500 but he gets $100 discount so he has to pay only $400 . Now the remaining $100 will be diposited from admins account to the sellers account . so the seller gets $400 from buyer and $100 from admin in a single transaction .

Is it possible in Paypal ? Your ideas/suggestions would be helpful. Please do it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no single API call that would do what you are looking for. You could code it where you accept the payment and then make a 2nd payment out to the seller. You could even look into [Chained Payment Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) for part of it (You are the primary receiver and accept the payment and then chain most of that payment over to the secondary receiver).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with PayPal adaptive payments, using parallel payment.  It is the same as chained, except there is no primary leg.  All the payment legs would have the same receiver, 6 is total number of receivers in the parallel case.

To reverse if either fails: reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError to true

How do you intend to authorize the payment?  If you are using the admins credentials to make API call this might work.  Buyer explicitly approves payment, admin (since his credentials) implicitly approves payment.